# MapServer merging features from layers in Template-Driven Output

Tags: geojson, wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo, template

I want to get **WMS** `GetFeatureInfo` result in **GeoJSON** format from **MapServer**. Result should be valid **GeoJSON** `FeatureCollection` containing array of `features` from one or more layers.

I use **Template-Driven Output** (https://mapserver.org/output/template_output.html) with external template single file.

Template file (`my.tmpl`) is referenced in map file:

```
OUTPUTFORMAT
  NAME "geojson"
  DRIVER "TEMPLATE"
  FORMATOPTION "FILE=my.tmpl"
END
```

Template file (`my.tmpl`) looks like (two layers with Point geometry, having simple properties set):

```
// MapServer Template
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [

[resultset layer=layer1]
[feature trimlast=","]
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [ [shpxy precision=6] ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": [num]
  }
},
[/feature]
[/resultset]

<------ How to put ',' optional separator here?

[resultset layer=layer2]
[feature trimlast=","]
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ [shpxy precision=6] ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "id": [number],
      "name": "[name]"
  }
},
[/feature]
[/resultset]

]}
```

It works, but there is problem to put ',' separator between `resultsets` from several layers.
Using `trimlast` option in `[feature]` tag is essential to remove ',' separator after last feature in layer results.

Is there any support for conditional template output in **MapServer**? I.e. output string if some condition (for example, 'featureNumber == featureCount') is satisfied ?

Comment: Did you get it working? Similar situation for me.

Comment: Currently I use a workaround - the proxy service, which is exposed to clients and it performs post-processing of received response from `MapServer` (along with clients authorization and other tasks, which can't be implemented in MapServer)